# Detener ataque DDoS con Apache + Fail2ban

Tags: apache, seguridad

Escribo porque tengo un problema que no estoy pudiendo solucionar...
Tengo un servidor el cual recibe por momentos ataques de denegación de servicio desde distintas IPs.

La gran mayoría de estos ataques los he detenido utilizando Apache + Fail2ban, denegando el acceso mediante iptables a toda IP que realice más de 10 peticiones simultáneas por segundo.
El problema que tengo es que log de Apache determinado por el LogFormat, comitea en el access log de forma desordenada a veces. 
Esto debido a que distintas peticiones tienen distinto tamaño. Y puede que una petición realizada un segundo después que otra, sea guardada en el log antes que la que se hizo primero. Con lo cual Fail2ban no reconoce los intentos como simultáneos cuando hay un ataque y el mismo obviamente entra y afecta el servidor.

Estuve tratando de buscar modificar el LogFormat de Apache para que las peticiones sean logueadas en el orden en que se realizaron, sin importar la duración o peso de la misma, sin lograr hacerlo.
Les consulto, alguien ha padecido algo parecido y encontró una solución para que Apache loguee las peticiones ordenadamente?...

Muchas Gracias !!

Comment: Has probado mod_evasive?? de apache

Comment: [mod_evasive para CentOS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-against-dos-and-ddos-with-mod_evasive-for-apache-on-centos-7)

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Si lo he probado pero no dió resultado, estimo que algo no ha quedado bien configurado ya que con dicho módulo activo no fue posible detener los ataques..

Comment: Buenas. Si el proyecto es un sitio web, puedes probar usar [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/es/). Este servicio te protege contra ddos y es gratuito para sitios personales. [Esta es una descripción de como funciona.](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205177068-Step-1-How-does-Cloudflare-work-)

Comment: El cloudfire que fue citato arriba es muy útil, muchos sitios grandes utilizan la plataforma de cdn de ellos para sostener los ataques de Ddos, Lo más interesante, es que el servicio es gratuito dependiendo del paquete que usted necesita.

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?